# Create Floating Action Button in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, controls

I want to create a floating action button. This button is like an add button on Google mail in android, if we tapped then the screen goes dark and showed a few sub-button with good animation. This is the example in [github](https://github.com/yoavlt/LiquidFloatingActionButton)

[image: floating button]

At first, I did search at cocoacontrols but found nothing so I decide to create my own.
But I have no clue how to do that, so my question is how to create that?

Any help or pointer to some useful link will appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what a float action button is.  Looking at your picture, I have no clue as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi, @ElTomato This button is like an add button on Google mail in android, if we tapped in then the screen goes dark and showed a few sub-button with good animation.

Comment: you should use custom cell for each button display and reload tableview on action of button click event use popover animation to show transparent dark view..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it by presenting a `CustomViewController` above your current view controller use below code for that

```
self.viewControllerObj.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:self.viewControllerObj animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you want to see background view with `shade effect` you can set `Opacity` for your `Background color` of the presenting `viewcontroller`

For getting a moving effect for your buttons give animation to them please find some sample code below,

```
CGRect tempSize = button.frame;
tempSize.origin.y -= 50;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; // animate the following:
button.frame = tempSize; // move to new location
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Hei thank you, I made it with presenting modal presentation as you said over it and use a little animation.

Answer (score 0):

it's not a "floating button",it's another view with black ground color with alpha 0.3.
You add your button and add the view onto the origin view or your window layer like this.

```
UIWindow *window            = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
_bgView                     = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, Main_Screen_Width, Main_Screen_Height)];
//add your buttons here on the _bgView
//create buttons
_bgView.backgroundColor     = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.3];
[window addSubview:_bgView];
```

should accomplish the effect you want

Comment: Or can we just presented a modal presentation over it?

Answer (score 0):

Swift Version of arunjos007 answer:

```
viewControllerObj.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
present(viewControllerObj, animated: true)
```